# Centering text underneath image

Tags: html, css

I have three image sections:

```html
img section{
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
}
img section two{
 float:center;
 text-align:center;
 }
img section three
 float:right;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

and I tried putting text-align:center on all of them but it won't center it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgK2B.png

This is a image of one of the texts I'm trying to center.

HTML:

```html
<section class ="img_section">
<div>
<img src="images/cafepicture.png" alt="Cafe Inside"> 
<br>
<p>insert text</p><br>
</div>
</section>
```

I am pretty useless at html so any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying `text-align: center;` to the `<p>` tag and give it a width (make sure your section has a width too).

Also, unrelated, you shouldn't need those `<br>` tags. Clear your float in the CSS too. I have included inline styles to demonstrate:

```html
<section class="img_section" style="width: 150px;">
  <img src="images/cafepicture.png" alt="Cafe Inside"> 
  <p style="width: 100%; text-align: center; clear: left;">insert text</p>
</section>
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gQLj5.png It worked but I didn't center it? It's more right aligned now.

Comment: I would set the width of the section element equal to the width of the image and then it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: One more thought... you could also set the width of the `<p>` tag to be the same as the image width and/or remove the width style property altogether.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wWIss.png it worked! ...But now they're REALLY close together

Comment: Nevermind. I have fixed it. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the width of the img and text by changing the width on each css tag.

```css
        div.img_section {
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 150px;
    }
    img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .text {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="img_section">
            <img src=""/>
            <p class="text">text below img here<p>
        </div>
```

Hopefully this helps, the img has a width and height because i don't actually have an image there it's just a div with a background.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of those occasions where I think you can justifiably use a presentational table to aid in layout - (others may disagree):

The 1st table row has cells with image,image,image, the 2nd row has desc,desc,desc.

This produces an easy solution.

For those who dislike this idea, you can achieve the same effect with 2 divs set to display:table each containing 3 divs with display:table-cell. You will need to set text-align:center (table cells in a table do this automatically).

Other solutions are available... see flexbox